# How to properly place dynamically created objects in a groupBox?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to populate some labels and trackbars inside a groupBox. I'm using a List to define the count of them. But i'm having trouble to placing them correctly. This form will be a simple poll about personnel and when i select a personel from comboBox, questions will be pulled from a csv file and stored in a List to use in several parts of program.

Here's my current code:

```
private void InitializeUI()
    {
        pList = Database_IO.ParsePersonelData();
        fList = Database_IO.ParseFactorData();

        foreach (Personel p in pList)
        {
            personelCB.Items.Add(p.personelName + " " + p.personelSurname);
        }

        List<Label> labels = new List<Label>();
        List<TrackBar> tBars = new List<TrackBar>();
        foreach (Factor f in fList)
        {
            Label l = new Label
            {
                Text = f.factorName
            };
            labels.Add(l);
            this.Controls.Add(l);
            l.Parent = evalGroup;


            TrackBar t = new TrackBar();
            tBars.Add(t);
            this.Controls.Add(t);
            t.Parent = evalGroup;
        }
    }
```

And this is what i'm trying to do. Dynamically. How can i achieve this?

[image: And this is what i'm trying to do. Dynamically.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.Controls.Add(t)` adds trackbar to Form container. You should rather add it to groupBox container:

`evalGroup.Controls.Add(t)`

You also have to place them accordingly using `Location` property and `DockStyle`

Comment: Ah thank you! As you can see, i was desperately trying to make those children of groupBox (but failed terribly). But i still need to fix Dock and Location. There was Grid Layout in Java, is there anything similar in c#? So i can easily place them.

Comment: I suggest TableLayoutPanel, it's a bit tricky in the beginning to use it, but it gives all the positioning control you need.